# Qt MOC error for namespace like FOO::BAR

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces, moc

I've got a namespace like

```
namespace FOO::BAR {
    [..] myNameSpaceContent [..]
}
```

The MOC compiler spots an error on the first ligne. This error disappears when I put :

```
namespace FOO {
    namespace BAR {
        [..] myNameSpaceContent [..]
    }
}
```

Do you happen to know how I can solve that MOC problem ?

Comment: Didn't you just found the fix yourself ?

Comment: @EricFortin: I guess no, because the OP does not know that the first is not valid C++.

Comment: This is valid C++17 code, apparently Qt MOC does not support it prior to version 5.8 as noted on https://github.com/SFTtech/openage/issues/1043#issuecomment-429622677

Answer (score 2):

It is not a MOC problem, but rather a C++ issue;

```
namespace FOO::BAR {
```

is not valid syntax prior to C++17, unfortunately. Only

```
namespace FOO { namespace BAR {
```

is okay.

Comment: As of C++17, `namespace FOO::BAR {` is value syntax.